# fstab folder mounting not working

Tags: mount, virtualbox, fstab, automount, shared-folders

I was following this guide on [how to mount VirtualBox shared folders](https://gist.github.com/estorgio/0c76e29c0439e683caca694f338d4003). I've done every thing said in the guide. but the the folder is not auto-mounted when Ubunut is booted. i can mount it manually as the guide explains and everything works fine but auto-mounting part seems broken. it doesn't give me an error or anything at all. it just seems that it's not working

The folder can be mounted manually:
[image]

fstab file:
[image]

Module file:
[image]

- I'm running ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on VirtualBox 7.0.6